# Confusion in identity theorem of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have a small doubt related to the identity theorem

> Let $f(z) $ be an entire function and there exist some nonconstant sequence $z_n$ such that\begin{equation}
> z_n =
>     \begin{cases}
>         1/n & \text{if }n = 2m, m \in \mathbb{N}\\
>          n & \text{if } n = 2m-1, m \in \mathbb{N}
>     \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
> such that $f(z_n)=0 $.

> Means we say the analytic function is constant if the limit point of the sequence of zeros lies inside the domain of analyticity of the function.
> My doubt is whether is it necessary for entire functions to be constant (Using identity theorem) the all the subsequences of the sequence of zeros are convergent only Is it enough to have one subsequence whose limit belongs to the domain of analyticity?

Question: Is $f(z) $ a constant function?

My guess is "yes" the function is identically zero in such condition also and it is because "when some analytic function in domain D have zero that means there is a small disc (say$\Delta$) around that zero such that $f(z)=0 \forall z \in \Delta$

I'm on the right track,

Any comment is well appreciated.

Comment: What does "odd terms go to infinity such that $f(z_n)=0$" mean?

Comment: means that "sequence have some divergent subsequence such that $f(z_n)=0"$

Comment: $z_n= 1/n $ when $n$ is even and  $z_n= 1/2 , 1/3, 1/2,1/3, 1/2, 1/3 .... $ when $n$ is odd. basically, $z_n$ is divergent but has some subsequence also which have limit point in the domain of analyticity.

Comment: @user1551 "Divergent" means oscillating divergent in the unit disc.

Comment: OR Let me put doubt in the words "For an analytic function f which have a  subsequence(z_{nk}) of zeros (may be the sequence  z_n may not convergent) in the domain of analyticity function f is identically zero for all z in the domain. I hope this is understandable. Thanks

Comment: Please someone reply

Comment: @user1551 I have edit my question

Comment: @user1551 I just want to construct a sequence such that it has a limit in D but NOT all its subsequences converging to the same limit, Does in such cases identity theorem give the results?

Comment: Just apply the identity theorem to the subsequence $(w_n) = (z_{2n})$. Then $w_n \to 0$ and $f(w_n) = 0$, so that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: In the definition of your $z_n$, you have a $p$ for the odd terms. Is that meant to be $n$?

Comment: @Arthur yes, it's typo mistake